# Zoom on domain axes with JFreeChart

Tags: charts, jfreechart

Is there a way to zoom along the x-axis in bar charts created with JFreeChart?
I saw i can zoom in both directions if the graph contains time series but i would like to do that even in presence of a normal bar chart. This is particularly useful when there are hundreds of bars.

Following there is my code:

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for(int i=1;i<201;i++)
            dataset.addValue(rand.nextInt(50) + 1, "test", ""+i);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(title,       // chart title
        "pages",                  // domain axis label
        "Value", dataset,         // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
        true,                     // include legend
        true,                     // tooltips?
        false                     // URLs?
        );

        ChartPanel chart_panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chart_panel.setMouseZoomable(true);
        chart_panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        //renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, color_map.get(entity));
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        this.add(chart_panel);
```

[image]

Comment: Try [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SlidingCategoryDataset).

Comment: Same behavior. The problem is that each key inside the dataset is seen as a String and not as a number and the result is that the zoom is disabled in the x direction. Using a timeSeries dataset where keys are temporal instances enables the x-zoom but i do have numbers and not temporal instances.

Comment: I meant to suggest using `SlidingCategoryDataset` _instead_ of zooming.